# Stability of ODE x'=Ax+f(x)

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

Let $\phi \in C^1([0,\infty); R)$ and $\phi' \in C^{0,1}([0,\infty);R) $ and $\phi'(0)=0$  Define $f:R \rightarrow R$ via $$f(x)=\phi'(|x|)\frac{x}{|x|}$$ Then show

(a) $f \in C^{0,1}(R^n;R^n)$ and $f(0)=0$.

(b) Suppose $\phi$ is twice differentiable in $[0,r)$ for some $r>0$, and there exists $C$,$\alpha >0$ s.t. $|\phi"(s)| \leq C|s|^\alpha$ for some $s \in [0,r)$, show that $$|f(x)| \leq C|x|^{1+\alpha}$$ for all $x \in B(0,r)$

(c) Suppose $A \in R^{n*n}$ be antisymmetric, then find a $f \in C^{0,1} (R^n;R^n)$ s.t. 0 is an unstable equilibrium point for the ODE $$x'=Ax+f(x)$$

(d) Same assumption as (c), find a $f \in C^{0,1} (R^n;R^n)$ s.t. 0 is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point for the ODE $$x'=Ax+f(x)$$

I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Speaking about parts (c) and (d): do you know special properties of system $x' = Ax$ when the matrix $A$ is skew-symmetric?

Comment: @Evgeny Yeah, the eigenvalues are either 0 or pure imaginary numbers. So, the real part of the eigenvalues are non-negative. But I don't know if the eigenvalues of a skew symmetric can have multiplicity greater than 1, because I want to check the stability of point 0 for the ODE x'=Ax.

Comment: What was important here is that $\exp {At}$ is a family of orthogonal transformations and hence saves the norm of any vector. System $x' = Ax$ thus has a conserved quantity $x^T x$ which can be used as a first candidate for Lyapunov function of $x' = Ax +f(x)$. For a continuation, study @Futurologist answer: it has everything in details (and I wish I were able to put "Spoiler Alert!" on it, but it would be strange :) )

Answer (score 1):

What does $C^{0,1}\big([0, \infty), \mathbb{R}\big)$ stand for? Does it mean continuous and Lipschitz? Which points do you have problems with?

For (c) and (d) you can apply Lyapunov stability with Lyapunov function. Take the smooth, quadratic function $V(x) = \frac{1}{2} |x|^2 = \frac{1}{2}(x\cdot x)$. Then $V$ is a Lyapunov function because it is defined everywhere, $V(0)=0$ and $V(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}.$ Now let $x(t)$ be a solution of $$x' = A\,x + f(x) = A\,x + \phi'\big(|x|\big) \, \frac{x}{|x|}$$
Then \begin{align}\frac{d}{dt} V\big(x(t)\big) &= \frac{1}{2}\, \frac{d}{dt}\big(x(t) \cdot x(t)\big) = \big(x \cdot x'\big) = \big(x \cdot  (A\,x + f(x))\big)  =   \big(x \cdot  A\,x\big) +  \big(x \cdot f(x)\big)\\
&=  \big(x \cdot  A\,x\big) +  \left(x \, \cdot \, \phi'(|x|) \, \frac{x}{|x|}\right) =  \big(x \cdot  A\,x\big) +   \phi'(|x|)  \, \left(x \, \cdot \, \frac{x}{|x|}\right) \\
&= \big(x \cdot  A\,x\big) +   \frac{\phi'(|x|)}{|x|}  \, \left(x \, \cdot \,  x\right) = \big(x \cdot  A\,x\big) +   \frac{\phi'(|x|)}{|x|}  \, |x|^2\\
&= \big(x \cdot  A\,x\big) +   \phi'(|x|)  \, |x|
\end{align}
Now, since $A$ is antisymmetric, $(x \cdot Ax) = (A^*x \cdot x) = -(A x \cdot x) = -(x \cdot Ax)$ is true for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, which means that $(x \cdot Ax) = 0$. Consequently,
 $$\frac{d}{dt} V\big(x(t)\big) = \phi'\big(\,|x(t)|\,\big)\, |x(t)|$$

(c) If $\phi(s)$ is a strictly increasing function on the interval $[0, \infty)$, then $\phi'(s) > 0$ and thus for a non-equilibrium solution $x(t)$ of $x' = A\,x + f(x)$ 
$$\frac{d}{dt} V\big(x(t)\big) = \phi'\big(\,|x(t)|\,\big)\, |x(t)| > 0$$ which means that the equilibrium point $x_0 = 0$ is unstable since if we invert time $t \mapsto -t$ the point will be asymptotically stable (in other words, if we go back in time, the trajectories near $0$ are attracted to it).

(d) If $\phi(s)$ is a strictly decreasing function on the interval $[0, \infty)$, then $\phi'(s) < 0$ and thus for a non-equilibrium solution $x(t)$ of $x' = A\,x + f(x)$ 
$$\frac{d}{dt} V\big(x(t)\big) = \phi'\big(\,|x(t)|\,\big)\, |x(t)| < 0$$ which means that the equilibrium point $x_0 = 0$ is asymptotically stable.